# Assigning default role to EXTERNALLY IDENTIFIED Oracle user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, single-sign-on

So, I need to implement SSO in our Oracle databases (using Standard Edition only) and I'm nearly there but I have one annoying problem.

Here's the basic run down of how the user is created. This all works beautifully and I can connect without usernames or passwords. No error are thrown when I GRANT the role of assign it as default

```
CREATE USER "OPS$DOMAIN\USER" IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;
GRANT create session  TO "OPS$DOMAIN\USER";
GRANT my_awesome_role TO "OPS$DOMAIN\USER";

ALTER USER "OPS$DOMAIN\USER" DEFAULT ROLE my_awesome_role;
```

But when i log in, the role doesn't appear when running

```
SELECT * FROM session_roles
```

and I need to specifically run the SET ROLE command to bring it to life

```
SET ROLE my_awesome_role
```

So my question is, do I need to do something different with roles when using external authentication in Oracle? The documentation is a little vague, or at least my reading of it is ;-)

Comment: What's the parameter `OS_ROLES` set to? If it is set to true then the operating system completely manages the role grants for all database usernames. Your code is working perfectly and the user has the default role in my test environment.

Comment: It's 0. Let me research that .... Thanks!